# Using a single function to find min and max numbers in a list without using a driver function?

Tags: list, recursion, functional-programming, scheme

I am currently confused with the idea behind functional programming in general. I currently have a working solution to my problem (That is, finding the min and max of a list, and returning these in a new list) but to do that, my solution essentially requires 3 functions, and this bothers me, because I am sure there is a way to do it with just 1 function in scheme.

So.. my question is, how do I combine the outputs of 2 functions into 1 concise function? (The driver function)

Here is what I have...

```
(define (findMax lst) ; Find and return maximum number in a list
 (cond [(null? lst) '()]
       [(= (length lst) 1) (list-ref lst 0)]
       [(> (list-ref lst 0) (list-ref lst (- (length lst) 1))) (findMax (drop-right lst 1))]
       [(< (list-ref lst 0) (list-ref lst (- (length lst) 1))) (findMax (cdr lst))]
       (else
        (findMax (cdr lst))
        )
       )
  )

(define (findMin lst) ; Find and return smallest number in a list
 (cond [(null? lst) '()]
       [(= (length lst) 1) (list-ref lst 0)]
       [(> (list-ref lst 0) (list-ref lst (- (length lst) 1))) (findMin (cdr lst))]
       [(< (list-ref lst 0) (list-ref lst (- (length lst) 1))) (findMin (drop-right lst 1))]
       (else
        (findMin (cdr lst))
        )
       )
  )
```

I use a driver function to take both of these functions, and make a new list shown here:

```
(define (findEnds lst)
  (list (findMin lst) (findMax lst))
  )
```

So essentially, if given a list:

```
(6 7 8 4 9 2)
```

the output would be:

```
(2 9)
```

I know there is some way to use lambda possibly to do all of this in 1 function, but I need to be pointed in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my version (note that I've changed it to return the result as a single dotted pair, rather than a list with two elements<sup>†</sup>):

```
(define (min/max lst)
  (if (empty? lst)
      #f
      (let ((next (min/max (cdr lst))))
        (define cur (car lst))
        (if (not next)
            (cons cur cur)
            (cons (min (car next) cur) (max (cdr next) cur))))))
```

Example:

```
> (min/max '(3 1 4 1 5 9))
(1 . 9)
```

† If you really want to use a list of two elements, change all the `cons` to `list`, and change the `(cdr next)` to `(cadr next)`.

Comment: My use of `let` just defines a local variable that holds the result of the recursion (you don't want to recurse over the same sublist more than once!). The first `if` is there to handle the base case (return `#f`, the false value, if there are no remaining elements), and the second `if` is there to handle a `#f` return from the recursion. Good luck with learning the code!

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a really good challenge that might help with learning some Scheme concepts. I've implemented `min/max` using [fold-left](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/control.html#./control:s38). It might also be fun using a [named-let](http://www.scheme.com/tspl4/further.html#./further:s41)

```
(define (min/max lst)      
  (fold-left 
    (lambda (acc num)
      (cons (min num (car acc)) (max num (cdr acc))))
    (cons +inf.0 -inf.0)
    lst))
```

Comment: I would not advise using `(cons +inf.0 -inf.0)` as the initial value. If anything, use `#f` (in a similar style to my solution). That's because using `+inf.0` and `-inf.0`, which are inexact numbers, forces the result of calling `min` and `max` to be inexact, also.

Comment: Hmmm I thought about that too, but obviously we can't say `(min #f num)`, so I was lazy and picked `+inf.0`